# What would be an example of an improper function?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, definition, convex-optimization, examples-counterexamples

I'm reading a text by rockafellar and wets and in it, it defines the so called proper and improper function
[image]

What could be a concrete example of a function that is not proper? I failed to think up one.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105842/improper-convex-function for an example. (One that's convex, even.)

Comment: Please ... capital letters on names of authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For every proper convex function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists some $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \geq x \cdot b - \beta$ for every x.